# How to replace a functor call by a lambda call in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have an abstract template class

```
template <typename T>
class Predicate1
{
  public:

    Predicate1();

    virtual ~Predicate1();

    virtual bool operator() (const T item) const = 0;
};
```

an implementation

```
class Pred : public Predicate1<string>
{
  public:

    virtual bool operator() (const string item) const;
};


bool Pred::operator()(const string item) const
{
  return item == "";
}
```

and a template class with a method `filter` that takes a predicate:

```
template <typename T>
class TList : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<TList<T> >
{
  public:

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<const TList<T> > List;

    const List filter(const Predicate1<T>& p) const;

    ...
};
```

I then use the filter as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const TList<string>::List l1 = ...;

  const TList<string>::List l2 = l1->filter(Pred());
}
```

which works OK.
However, I do not know how to replace the functor with an anonymous function.
I have tried:

```
const TList<string>::List l2 =
  l1->filter([] (const string item) -> bool { return item == ""; });
```

The anonymous function has, as far as I understand, the same signature as the
functor's `()` operator, so it should work. Instead, I get the compiler error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘TList<std::basic_string<char> >::filter(main(int, char**)::<lambda(std::string)>) const’
note: candidate is: const TList<T>::List TList<T>::filter(const Predicate1<T>&) const [with T = std::basic_string<char>, TList<T>::List = boost::shared_ptr<const TList<std::basic_string<char> > >]
```

So, somehow the types seem to be incompatible, but I do not understand if I have overlooked something or what I am doing wrong. Or in other words, how do I have to declare the `filter` method so that it can (only) accept an anonymous function with signature

```
const string -> bool
```

or, in general, `const T -> bool`?

Comment: Returning new objects as `shared_ptr`s, abstract base classes for functors, you're used to Java, right? (no offence, just sprang to my eye) ;)

Comment: I also use Java but I am mainly a C++ programmer and work in a C++-only project. No offence taken, but why would `shared_ptr` be a Java idiom? Or what is the idiomatic way of sharing an object graph in C++ and have it destroyed when it goes out of scope?

Comment: It's just that a list seems like a pretty value-like object and creating instances of it dynamically and moving pointers around instead of values at least looks a bit uncommon. But then again, I don't have complete insight into your project and maybe a list should indeed be dynamically created object in your scenario.

Comment: @Christian "value-like object and creating instances of it dynamically and moving pointers around instead of values at least looks a bit uncommon": I am trying to implement lists as an algebraic data type. Nothing to do with Java, rather with SML. I am trying to implement immutable functional lists and define the usual operations (`map`, `filter`, `fold`, ...) that take lambdas as arguments. I got everything to work apart from the "writing a method / higher-order function that takes a lambda" because I did not know how to define the signature of such a method.

Comment: Ah Ok, got it. So the returned list isn't exactly of type `TList`, but some derived type. So you're using dynamic allocation because you need dynamic polymorphism, makes sense.

Comment: Yes. `TList<T>` is abstract too. It has two subclasses `Nil<T>` and `Cons<T>`. I do not use a NULL pointer to mark the end of the list, but an instance of `Nil<T>` (that has a method `isEmpty()` returning `true`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of writing your own interface classes, use `std::function`:

```
const List filter(const std::function<bool (const T)>& p) const;
```

`std::function` has constructors from lambdas and functors, so you can continue to use `Pred`.

Comment: Thanks. This solves my current programming problem (+1) but does not explain what is wrong with my code. Of course I can look up the source code for the constructor std::function(). I hope I can understand more from that.

Comment: @Giorgio The problem is simply, that a lambda has a type completely different from `Predicate1`. You take a reference to `Predicate1`, so can only pass in classes derived from it (which a lambda obviously isn't). The major problem here is that you try to mix dynamic and static polymorphism. You define your own abstract base class for functors, to make all functors derive from it. But then you try to call `filter` with a completely different type not derived from `Predicate1`.

Comment: @Christian Rau: I understand the problem now, however, I would still be curious to understand how the constructor of the template class `std::function` can recognize a lambda or a functor object. I would like to see what happens if I use the same signature of this constructor for the `filter` method.

Comment: @ecatmur: Thanks for the hint, it compiles now.

Comment: @Giorgio Well, `std::function` is a bit of a magic class to the outside (while being quite obvious once you undertand its internals). In fact it uses type erasure to transform the static type of its target function (its constructor is just a template, taking anything you want) into a dynamic type internally. So you can have the same `std::function` store any type possible internally, while still being the same `std::function` and not being templated itself (ok, it is templated but only on the signature and not the actual functor type).

Comment: @Christian Rau: So if I understand correctly there is no way to define the signature directly (using C++ syntax) and one must use `std::function` instead.

Comment: @Giorgio a signature isn't an object type, so you can't use it directly.  A signature used within a parameter list decays to the equivalent function pointer type, but that can't be used for stateful (closing) callables.  That means if you want your method to take a single type it needs to erase the actual type, and `std::function` is one way to do this.

Comment: @Giorgio You could however take an arbitrary type yourself, by just making filter a template on the functor, without the need for a `std::function`: `template<typename F> const List filter(const F &fn)` and then calling `fn(item)` as usual (keep in mind to take it by const-ref and not by value if you want your polymorphic `Predicate` things to call the proper implementation when used). But that in turn would allow anything and not just functions with a signature of `bool(T)`.